# How can I make VS Code suggest snippets at the top of the suggestion list?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to use code snippets in VS Code. But when I type, for example, `for` in javascript file, the IntelliSense doesn't suggest snippet "for-loop" - I need to manually scroll the dropdown and select it. Is there any way to make VS Code to suggest snippets at first?

UPD: I have found the person with same problem, but he has no answers - [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/visual-studio-code-for-snippets-if-snippets-etc.383518/)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You need to use `editor.snippetSuggestions` config option with `"top"` value. Please, see [Customizing IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense) article for more tips and tricks.

Answer (score 12):

There is one more way to deal with this issue by setting 
"editor.tabCompletion": true, 
that way whenever there is a snnipet available it will use it automatically without even opening the list by using tab twice.

1. File > Preferences > Settings (Code > Preferences > Settings on Mac)
2. open "Editor" menu on the left
3. edit "editor.tabCompletion": true

more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense

Comment: It has changed now: it is "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets"

Answer (score 11):

Now that VS Code mostly abstracted away the `settings.json` file, you can do the instructions shown by Kavu, with this bonus tip:

- go to Preferences > Settings
- find the `Search settings` text input, at the top
- type in "snippet"

The setting should be at the top of the result set:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Setting `editor.snippetSuggestions` to `top` only works for certain snippets: `for` but not `foreach`. With `top`, the snippet does appear higher in the completion list, but for some reason the keyword version is what is highlighted, with the snippet option scrolled out of view (and the scrollbar quickly fades, giving the impression there's nothing hidden)

The `editor.tabCompletion` to `true` approach works for both `for` and `foreach`.