# How to change Intellisense priority in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change the priority of the abbreviation recommendations inside Visual Studio Code? The file in question is a `.scss` file and I have tried with and without the Sass extension in Code installed. As far as I can tell currently it just lists them out in an alphabetical order. Is there any way to change this? I am genuinely surprised about how many people praise this editor when it has such huge flaws, that to my knowledge aren't solved yet.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26127 says to "Disable the quick suggestions altogether" ?!

[image: Visual Studio Code recommending <code>flex-flow</code> instead of <code>font-family</code>]

Comment: highly related question but not a dup-target since this question also seems to involve Emmet abbreviation suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863609/vs-code-intellisense-dont-suggest-snippet-at-first

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In VS Code 1.16 (the current [insiders build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders)) you can force emmet suggestions to the top by [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings):

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
"emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true
```

[image]

Comment: 1.16 should come out sometime this week for everyone as well

Comment: So far, it's doing it's job. It's really weird that this has only been implemented in an insiders build but better late  than never. Thanks