# Auto Complete list is not providing the best results

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm having a bunch of issues regarding the auto completion of my typed objects that Visual Studio Code is giving a bunch of non relevant auto complete on my functions and i have to scroll half way the list to find the correct ones.

[image]
[image]

I've tried disabling all my extensions and restarting the TS Server. any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Comment: Maybe relevant issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66621, and possible solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37863609/vs-code-intellisense-dont-suggest-snippet-at-first

Comment: this was helpful. i had to disable a few things to get it to work.

Comment: Would you mind posting what you did as an answer here so others know how to solve it as well?